# Trying to boot from USB, but the screen stays on gnu grub version 2.02

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, startup

How do I fix this so that i get to use the GUI desktop.  I want to run ubuntu 17 from the disk.

Comment: Need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the USB flash drive into a USB port. Power on the computer, hit the (typically) F12 key (or other key called out on the splash screen) to reach the `Boot Menu`. This occurs before you see the GRUB screen. Select USB from that menu and if you've built a bootable USB flash drive, it'll boot up. Then at the GRUB menu, choose `Try Ubuntu`.